# Get SQL data via listbox

Tags: sql, listbox

Ok, so what I am trying to do is click one item in a listbox that i have, that listbox gets data from the sql database depending on that the user types into the textbox.

Now when I click that item in the first listbox, I need more info related to that item to show up in the 2nd list box. 
When the user enters a name in the textbox, the first 10 in sql show up, now that I have that, I need to click on one of the items and get the 'task' of that client in the next listbox. Task is MATTERS in the database.

I am pretty sure that my code is correct, I get no errors but nothing shows up in the list box.

Here is my code:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string item = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

   if (listBox1.ContainsFocus)
   {
       if (item == "")
       {

       }
       else
       {
           var con2 = Conn.ConnString();

           using (SqlConnection myConnection2 = new SqlConnection(con2))
           {
               string oString2 = "select CLIENTMATTERS.MATTER, CLIENTMATTERS.DESCRIPTION from CLIENTMATTERS join CLIENTCODES on CLIENTMATTERS.CLIENT = CLIENTCODES.CLIENT Where CLIENTCODES.DESCRIPTION = '@code1'";


               SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString2, myConnection2);
               oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code1", item);
               myConnection2.Open();

               oCmd.Connection.Open();
               List<string> codelist2 = new List<string>();

               using (SqlDataReader oReader2 = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
               {
                  if (oReader2.HasRows)
                  {
                     string value = string.Empty;
                     while (oReader2.Read())
                     {
                        codelist2.Add(oReader2["MATTER"].ToString());
                     }
                   }
               }

               this.listBox2.DataSource = codelist2;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `BindingList<>` instead of `List<>`.

The `List<>` doesn't implement the `ListChanged` event, so the ListBox doesn't get notified when the datasource changes.

In your example it would look like this:

```
BindingList<string> codelist2 = new BindingList<string>();
```

For further information take a look at 
[BindingList on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1%20%22BindingList%20on%20MSDN).